# Disable portrait orientation on tablet in angular app

Tags: html, css, angular, orientation, landscape

Currently I have an Angular app and I am trying to **disable portrait on tablet devices**.
The user should be forced to **use the app in landscape orientation on tablet** devices.

Do you have any idea how should I proceed?

Thank you!